# How to remove "To field" suggestions in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

The new Gmail interface look like this:

[image]

In old interface there is **drop down button** under mail where we can delete **contacts**. Now it is missing in new interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic Gmail (old version) had a drop-down at the top-left under Gmail for quick access to Contacts. Now this drop-down option has gone from new interface.

In the new interface you can see an square box on top-right near to bell icon. This has various Google applications:

[image]

Click on this square box, Contacts will be there, if its not there click on **More**, you will find the Contacts:

[image]

You can rearrange these products anytime by dragging them.